# Python libraries are not updated, except in ipython

Tags: python

I have used pip to update and install some libraries on a computer that hadd an old Numpy version. But it doesn't seem to be actually applied:

```
davidm@illergard:~$ python
Python 2.7.3 (default, Feb 27 2014, 19:58:35) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy
>>> numpy.__version__
'1.6.1'
```

Ipython, on the other hand, does see the new libraries:

```
davidm@illergard:~$ ipython
Python 2.7.3 (default, Feb 27 2014, 19:58:35) 
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 2.1.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
%quickref -> Quick reference.
help      -> Python's own help system.
object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.

In [1]: import numpy

In [2]: numpy.__version__
Out[2]: '1.8.1'
```

This would suggest Ipython is running a different Python. Let's see it:

```
davidm@illergard:~$ which python
/usr/bin/python
davidm@illergard:~$ which ipython
/usr/local/bin/ipython

davidm@illergard:~$ cat /usr/local/bin/ipython
#!/usr/bin/python
# EASY-INSTALL-ENTRY-SCRIPT: 'ipython==2.1.0','console_scripts','ipython'
__requires__ = 'ipython==2.1.0'
import sys
from pkg_resources import load_entry_point

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(
        load_entry_point('ipython==2.1.0', 'console_scripts', 'ipython')()
    )
```

The shebang corresponds to the very same Python! Virtualenv is not installed, so that is not the problem.

System information:

```
davidm@illergard:~$ uname -a
Linux illergard 3.2.0-65-generic #99-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jul 4 21:03:29 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

davidm@illergard:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS
Release:    12.04
Codename:   precise
```

Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9386048/ipython-reads-wrong-python-version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know the cause, and I will be happy if someone can point it out, but I found a solution. Running

```
sudo python ez_setup.py
```

from [ez_setup.py obtained here,](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools) magically solved the problem, and now python sees the updated libraries. No reinstallation was needed.